# template parameter type deduction misunderstanding

Tags: c++, c++17

I have a template function with a universal (forwarding) parameter, as shown below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
void foo(T&& arg)
{
    // Check the type of T
    if constexpr (std::is_lvalue_reference_v<T>) {
        std::cout << "T is an lvalue reference" << std::endl;
    } else if constexpr (std::is_rvalue_reference_v<T>) {
        std::cout << "T is an rvalue reference" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "T is neither lvalue nor rvalue reference" << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() 
{
    foo(10);
    return 0;
}
```

In this code, I have a function template foo with a universal (forwarding) reference parameter named arg. The purpose of this function is to check the type of the template parameter T.

In the main function, I call foo with the argument 10. Since 10 is an rvalue, I expect the result to be 'T is an rvalue reference.' However, when I compile and run this code in the "http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/" online compiler using the `g++ -std=c++17 -Wall -pthread -fno-elide-constructors -Qn main.cpp && ./a.out` flags, the actual output is `T is neither lvalue nor rvalue reference.`

My assumption is that the template type `T` would be deduced as `int&&` here. But I guess the result is `int` which is similar to the behavior of `decltype(10)`. Is the type deduction here the same as calling `decltype(X)`? Or is there any rule here?

*moreover:*

if call foo as below,

```
int x = 10;
foo(std::move(x));
```

the result is `T is neither lvalue nor rvalue reference` ? I expect `T is an rvalue reference`

Answer (score 4):

You are checking if `T` is an rvalue reference, when you should be checking if `T&&` is an rvalue reference.

The parameter type - which may be an lvalue reference and may be an rvalue reference - is `T&&`.

[Demonstrated in Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/bx41qYvKT)

---

With this fix, you will also **never** reach

```
std::cout << "T&& is neither lvalue nor rvalue reference" << std::endl;
```

It is impossible for `T&&` to *not be a reference*.

Answer (score 4):

With only one exception, template type parameters are not deduced to be reference types, and they are never deduced to be rvalue-references.

The one exception is what makes universal references work: when a function template accepts an argument of the form `T&&`, `T` is deduced to be an lvalue reference type if an lvalue is passed as that parameter.

So in your example:

- Given the call `foo(10)`, `T` is deduced to be `int`.  That makes the type of `arg` `int&&`.
- Given the call `foo(some_int)`, `T` is deduced to be `int&`.  That means the type of `arg` would be `int& &&`.  Since you can't have references to references the reference collapsing rules are applied and `int& &&` collapses to `int&`.